# How to make floating images accessible to screen readers in Microsoft Word?

Tags: ms-word, accessibility, figure, floating

My organisation now has a policy to make all documents accessible, and a long list of guidance how to do so. Most of the requirements are OK. Alt-text is only a small amount of work; sans-serif fonts may not be as nice as Times Roman, but they’re readable; spacing using paragraph formatting rather than carriage returns is good practice anyway.

But then there’s figures. On a paginated document, large figures look great floating with text wrapped around them, but terrible inline, because page breaks often cause huge blank gaps in the page before the inline image. Same goes for tables. But our accessibility guidance insists that only inline images/tables are acceptable for screen readers – and Word’s accessibility checker does as well, though the requirement is missing in [Microsoft’s accessibility documentation](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/make-your-word-documents-accessible-to-people-with-disabilities-d9bf3683-87ac-47ea-b91a-78dcacb3c66d).

Is there some way to make floating images (and floating tables) accessible, so that popular screen readers will know where to parse them in the context of the document? I'm expecting that the documents will be shared as an exported PDF, but even for screen readers to work with the DOCX file would be sufficient.

Comment: Side note, WCAG (Web Content Accessibility Guidelines) does not have any requirements concerning fonts. Any font requirements you have will have come internally from your company.  Sans-serif fonts are typically easier to read online whereas serif fonts are usually better when printed.

Comment: When you say floating images, do you mean an image that has its wrapping set to "in front of text" as opposed to images inline with wrapping set to "tight" or "square"?  Alt text applies to images no matter how they're wrapped. You can see this doc for how to navigate by floating images using a screen reader: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/use-a-screen-reader-to-explore-and-navigate-word-a16a93f4-163f-4f48-a246-78c2573d8953#bkmk_usenavipane_win_2

Comment: @slugolicious Thanks, yes, I mean floating at the top/bottom/side/centre/wherever on the page with text wrapped around, rather than in line with the text and formatted as a single large character. I've edited the question slightly to clarify.

Comment: Still trying to understand. What makes a floating element not accessible? The only thing I can think of is the reading order. Word, by default, is in edit mode. You have to change the screen reader to browse mode (INS+space for NVDA) to use the reading navigation keys as mentioned in the article in my previous comment. So as long as an image has alt text, the only thing I can think of to make it less accessible is trying to find the image with the screen reader.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds as though this is a 'flaw' (design fault) in Microsoft Word's accessibility checker, which doesn't understand text frames being used for table and image layout. Both @slugolicious and my organization's accessibility trainer confirm that having images and tables floating with no additional text apart from the caption is actually fine for modern screen readers.

My error was assuming that my organization's standards included 'No errors from Microsoft Accessibility Checker'. That is not the case.